# Gauss-Seidel real type relaxation in SV

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

For a behavioral model (not to be synthesized) I use a recurrent circuit.
All variables are of type real and all operations operate on the same time slot.

The simple example below can be found on [EDAplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/4sjk):

```
  fun fun1 (.in(x), .out(out1));
  fun fun2 (.in(x), .out(out2));
  sum sum  (.in1(out1), .in2(out2), .out(x));
```

The circuit converges to a steady state:

```
top.fun1:     in =        0, out =        0
top.fun2:     in =        0, out =        0
top.fun1:     in =      0.2, out =      0.1
top.fun2:     in =      0.2, out =      0.1
top.fun1:     in =     0.24, out =     0.12
top.fun2:     in =     0.24, out =     0.12
...
top.fun1:     in =     0.25, out =    0.125
top.fun2:     in =     0.25, out =    0.125
```

During relaxation, after an evaluation of instance fun1, instance fun2 is evaluated, but not yet using the just changed input.
This corresponds to a Gauss-Jacobi style operation.

For hardware, this parallel behaviour makes perfect sense and would possibly cause race conditions otherwise.
But for the behavioral model above, it might be preferable to operate in a Gauss-Seidel style:

```
top.fun1:     in =        0, out =        0
top.fun2:     in =        0, out =      0.1
top.fun1:     in =      0.1, out =     0.11
top.fun2:     in =     0.21, out =    0.121
top.fun1:     in =    0.231, out =   0.1231
...
top.fun2:     in =     0.25, out =    0.125
```

In order to serialize the flow of simulation, one could for example insert input delays, 
but I wonder if there is a more principled way to achieve this in a multi-module context.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways to introduce ordering in SystemVerilog.

1. Write procedural code like you would in software using placing statements in-between begin/end blocks.
2. Use delays or clocks to sequence execution of procedural code.

Of course, hardware design is a combination of both paradigms. That's true even when writing behavioral models in SystemVerilog.

BTW, your code can be simplified by writing like:

```
module sum(input real in1, in2, output real out);
  always_comb begin
    out = in1 + in2;
  end 
endmodule
```